# Does the nanda at the end of ここはどこなんだ mean "what"?

Tags: translation

Does the なんだ at the end of

> **ここは**どこなんだ

mean "what"?

Reason I'm asking for help on such a obvious question is my brain thinks なんだ is the explanatory んだ; which I know is wrong, but its the only answer my brain is supplying at the moment. And I doubt "なんだ" is "what", as that would make the full sentence translate as "What where is this place/here?" which does not sound correct in the least bit of sense.

Comment: Your brain is right.

Comment: This post might be of help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13472/9831

Comment: @AeonAkechi My brain is right on which part; nanda being the explanatory nda; or nanda being "what"?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey It's the explanatory んだ.

Comment: @AeonAkechi Can you copy and paste your comments into a answer for this question then; so that I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right in your speculation:

> なんだ is the explanatory んだ.